# jQuery Mobile - Fixed Header based on device orientation

Tags: jquery, mobile

im currently working on a website for mobile devices and im using jquery mobile.

I have my header in a fixed position by using:

```
<header data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
```

This works perfectly fine, however when the page is viewed on a device in landscape mode, the header takes up alot of the space.

Is it possible with jquery mobile to set data-position="fixed" only in portrait mode and have a NOT fixed header in landscape mode?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could bind to the `orientationchange` event and call `$("[data-position='fixed']").fixedtoolbar('hide');` on the header.

This is the jQuery Mobile page that talks about the methods available on the fixed tool bars http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-methods.html.

And these are the available events http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/api/events.html, one of which is `orientationchange`.

You can try using the actual selector shown with the data-position attribute rather than the #header. It might take a little bit of debugging to get it to work but no reason why it should not.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that?

Heres what i tried but it doesnt work:

 <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
   $("#header").fixedtoolbar('hide');
  });
 });
 </script>

The button works but nothing happens

Comment: Thanks alot! It works perfectly now, smooth and reliable, awesome.